# How can I only get the string from array that contains images using substr function

Tags: php

I try to cut a string from array to a specified length with PHP `substr()` function, but my problem is, in some cases, that array only contains images with no single string content on it.

My code:

```
<div class="ct f-light">
<?php
   $num_char = 255;
   $text = $in['content'];
   echo substr($text, 0, $num_char) . '...';
?>
</div>
```

`$in['content']` is an html. it was processed from CKEditor whichs contain both text and images.

This is the result if the array only contains a string:

[image]

and this is the result if it only contains images :

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide what `$in['content']` is in both examples? Perhaps, not cut it but hide the content you don't want with CSS.

Comment: yes is in. $in['content'] is array property that contain text and images both of it.

Comment: Please edit the question, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46382213/edit, and provide the values in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your $in['content'] look like? Is it in html? Or how did you mix images and text?

If you have that, I would suggest separating them. (into different variables) This would be the cleanest option. Alternatively, you can also search for the first image tag and then only use the text before that, like this:

```
$num_char = 255;
$text = explode('<img', $in['content'], 2)[0];
echo substr($text, 0, $num_char) . '...';
```

You then might also want to check for an empty string.

If you are not using html, please clarify what you are using.

(Also, in case you didn't notice, tags like `<p>` will count towards the 255 character limit, so there will most likely be less than 255 characters visible. Also this might result in bad (incomplete) html.)

Comment: yes $in['content'] is an html. it was processed from ckeditor. Actually if i used split() function it's work but give me error "Function split() is deprecated". So I use explode and woking fine. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Right, it is deprecated, I will change that in my answer. Since it is html, however, I would probably clean it up first, since you will get problems with incomplete a tags, for instance. (This might show something like `<a href="www.google.co` in clear text.)

Comment: Since that worked, would you mind closing the question? (accepting this answer) The cleaning of your html is a separate question